# Edge box detection using opencv python

Tags: python, opencv

Can any one give an example of edge box detection algorithm to generate proposals for object detection using open cv.
We can get the details from https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.0/d4/d0d/group__ximgproc__edgeboxes.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  First you will need to download the model file that is used for Edge Boxes [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_extra/blob/master/testdata/cv/ximgproc/model.yml.gz).  Once you do that, the following code below (taken from [their Github](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/blob/96ea9a0d8a2dee4ec97ebdec8f79f3c8a24de3b0/modules/ximgproc/samples/edgeboxes_demo.py)) can be used as an example for running the Edge Boxes algorithm.  In short, put the code below into a separate file called `edgeboxes_demo.py`, then in the terminal type in:

```
python model.yml.gz image_file
```

`model.yml.gz` is the model that you saved from the link above which I assume is in the same directory where the code is.  `image_file` is the path to the image you want to use for testing the algorithm.  The code will run the Edge Boxes algorithm then draw the detected boxes on the image in green:

```py
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':
    model = sys.argv[1]
    im = cv.imread(sys.argv[2])

    edge_detection = cv.ximgproc.createStructuredEdgeDetection(model)
    rgb_im = cv.cvtColor(im, cv.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    edges = edge_detection.detectEdges(np.float32(rgb_im) / 255.0)

    orimap = edge_detection.computeOrientation(edges)
    edges = edge_detection.edgesNms(edges, orimap)

    edge_boxes = cv.ximgproc.createEdgeBoxes()
    edge_boxes.setMaxBoxes(30)
    boxes = edge_boxes.getBoundingBoxes(edges, orimap)

    for b in boxes:
        x, y, w, h = b
        cv.rectangle(im, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 1, cv.LINE_AA)

    cv.imshow("edges", edges)
    cv.imshow("edgeboxes", im)
    cv.waitKey(0)
    cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

## Test Image

[image: Source image]

## Result

[image: Result]

Comment: Can you provide the example in Python please

Comment: No problem: https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/blob/96ea9a0d8a2dee4ec97ebdec8f79f3c8a24de3b0/modules/ximgproc/samples/edgeboxes_demo.py

Comment: Try first to look at examples from the standard project repository.