# Error "ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 4)" on official structured edge detection and edgeboxes example

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, edge-detection

I need help with OpenCV implementation of StructuredEdgeDetection based on the random forest based approach. I'm using [official demo](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/blob/96ea9a0d8a2dee4ec97ebdec8f79f3c8a24de3b0/modules/ximgproc/samples/edgeboxes_demo.py) and getting error on line 22 `ValueError: too many values to unpack`.

Here is python script:

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':
    model = './model.yml'
    im = cv.imread('./L8C5M.png')

    edge_detection = cv.ximgproc.createStructuredEdgeDetection(model)
    rgb_im = cv.cvtColor(im, cv.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    edges = edge_detection.detectEdges(np.float32(rgb_im) / 255.0)

    orimap = edge_detection.computeOrientation(edges)
    edges = edge_detection.edgesNms(edges, orimap)

    edge_boxes = cv.ximgproc.createEdgeBoxes()
    edge_boxes.setMaxBoxes(30)
    boxes = edge_boxes.getBoundingBoxes(edges, orimap)

    print(boxes)
    for b in boxes:
        x, y, w, h = b
        cv.rectangle(im, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 1, cv.LINE_AA)

    cv.imshow("edges", edges)
    cv.imshow("edgeboxes", im)
    cv.waitKey(0)
    cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

I'm expecting result like this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54843550/edge-box-detection-using-opencv-python)

Comment: full traceback please. you can [edit] your question. also add the output of `print(boxes)` because that's relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The method returns `(boxes, scores)`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dd/d65/classcv_1_1ximgproc_1_1EdgeBoxes.html#a822e422556f8103d01a0a4db6815f0e5), not just the boxes. That seems to have been changed between 2017 and 2019.

You should use this code:

```
(boxes, scores) = edge_boxes.getBoundingBoxes(edges, orimap)
```

Then the loop will work.

You encountered this issue because you're using an *outdated link* to that example. The link you have shows a version from 2017. That old code would work with a 2017/2018 release of OpenCV.

[The *current* version of the example, from 2019](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/blob/4.x/modules/ximgproc/samples/edgeboxes_demo.py#L30), corresponds to the *current* API. The current example shows the proper usage for the current API.

Here is the change: https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/commit/6ae9809b2e464b72810298b10c6cf4935886a0f1

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs in line `x, y, w, h = b` within the `for` loop.

The variable `boxes` is a tuple comprising of two `numpy` arrays

According to the code you want to draw bounding boxes found by the edge detection algorithm. In order to that, you need to iterate through the first array of variable `boxes`, i.e loop through `boxes[0]`

Change line number 21 to `for b in boxes[0]:` and proceed as usual.

**Sample output:**

[image]